# Require variable with HTML Webpack Plugin

Tags: webpack

based on this Example (https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin/tree/master/examples/custom-template) I created an similar setup which requires the sub html file via an environment var.

```
function generate_page(config) {
    var tempateUrl = config.templateUrl ? config.templateUrl : 'src/template.html';
    return new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename:  config.filename,
        template: tempateUrl,
        xhtml: true,
        environment: {templateUrl:  config. subTemplateUrl}
    });

}
```

My src/template.html requires this subtemplate:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<% require('html!'+ htmlWebpackPlugin.options.environment.templateUrl ) %>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I run `webpack  --progress --colors --watch -d` I just get that error:

```
ERROR in Template execution failed: Error: Cannot find module "."

ERROR in   Error: Cannot find module "."

  - template.html:57 webpackMissingModule
    /Users/xxx/PycharmProjects/webpack-test/src/template.html:57:47

  - template.html:57 
    /Users/xxx/PycharmProjects/webpack-test/src/template.html:57:125

  - template.html:62 module.exports
    /Users/xxx/PycharmProjects/webpack-test/src/template.html:62:4

  - index.js:228 
    [webpack-test]/[html-webpack-plugin]/index.js:228:16

  - util.js:16 tryCatcher
    [webpack-test]/[bluebird]/js/release/util.js:16:23

  - promise.js:503 Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler
    [webpack-test]/[bluebird]/js/release/promise.js:503:31

  - promise.js:560 Promise._settlePromise
    [webpack-test]/[bluebird]/js/release/promise.js:560:18

  - promise.js:597 Promise._settlePromiseCtx
    [webpack-test]/[bluebird]/js/release/promise.js:597:10

  - async.js:131 Async._drainQueue
    [webpack-test]/[bluebird]/js/release/async.js:131:12

  - async.js:136 Async._drainQueues
    [webpack-test]/[bluebird]/js/release/async.js:136:10
```

If I write the same subTemplateUrl in the template.html file instead of the variable everything works fine:

```
<% require('html!./test.html' ) %>
```

Comment: It doesn't work without context.
Try `<% require('html!./' +htmlWebpackPlugin.options.environment.templateUrl + '.html' ) %>`

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Comment: Now the error is gone, but the template is not included. I personally think that the environment from the webpack html plugin is not available at the moment when the require is executed. Perhaps is an issue of the plugin?

Answer (score 2):

```
${ require('html!./' +htmlWebpackPlugin.options.environment.templateUrl + '.html' ) }
```

I found whatever using ${ or <% that's ok. it's equal both they in this plugin. 
require must set loader path like this `html../`, the `../` can't pass from out.

`<%=require('html!./' +htmlWebpackPlugin.options.environment.templateUrl + '.html' ) %>` it's ok too.

but using the way that `${ require('html!' + htmlWebpackPlugin.options.environment.templateUrl + '.html' ) }`  (the path `./` include in the templateUrl variable) is not efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution. Additional to add the context it was necessary to change `<%`to `${`. I don't understand or know why, but it works.

`${ require('html!./' +htmlWebpackPlugin.options.environment.templateUrl + '.html' ) }`

Any idea why this is working?