# Webpack File/Image loader for images in .ejs template

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, ejs

Looks I am missing a setting for loading images in webpack configuration if the image tag is within my index.ejs template.

All my images in my html files in my project get properly renamed and load fine during my build, but the image tag in the .ejs file gets ignored.

i.e in my .ejs if I have `<img src="../../home.png">` it remains that way, but in normal html file it changes to `<img src="12345677.png">`

My current loaders :

```
loaders: [
            //HTML Files
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: 'html'
            },
            //Transpile ES6 to ES5
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel',
                query: {
                    presets: [
                        ["es2015", {"module": false}]
                    ]
                }

            },
            //Extract Normal CSS
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ loader : 'css?sourceMap!autoprefixer', publicPath: "../"})

            },
            //Bundle Less into CSS Code
            {
                test: /\.less$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ loader : 'css?sourceMap!autoprefixer!less?sourceMap', publicPath: "../"})
            },
            //Images
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot)$/,
                loader: 'file'
            }
        ]
```

and important plugins :

```
plugins.push(
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                hash: true,
                filename: 'index.html',
                template:  './src/index.ejs',
                favicon: './src/favicon.ico',
                inject : false
            }),
            // Write out CSS bundle to its own file:
            new ExtractTextPlugin({
                filename: 'css/[contenthash].styles.css',
                allChunks: true
            }),
        );
```

Comment: Which `HTMLWebpackPlugin` version are you using? [this](https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin/blob/master/migration.md#loaders-in-templates) describes how loaders inside templates are now supported in 2.0

Comment: @RedMercury thanks man! it was driving me crazy! it's working like a charm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think ***ejs has no image loader support***

You can try this link ***[underscore-template loader](https://github.com/emaphp/underscore-template-loader)*** to load the image files as suggested by [author](https://github.com/jantimon) in this [thread](https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin/issues/275)

The other loader for the webpack includes *[ejs-loader](https://github.com/okonet/ejs-loader)*

Comment: ugh the joy of webpack haha, another complicated loader library to understand. Ok will give this a try, thanks man.

Comment: does using this loader mean you have to change all the 'include' and 'require' requests  in the ejs files?

Answer (score 7):

Just to provide an updated answer.
In Webpack 4, you can load images in `.ejs` files without `html-loader`.

Change your `src` attribute in your `img` tags to:

```html
<!-- index.ejs -->
<img src="<%= require('../../home.png') %>" alt="image text">
```

Enable CommonJS module syntax with `esModule: false`

```js
// webpack.config.js
module: {
  rules: [
    ...,
    test: /\.(png|jpg|etc)$/,
    use: [{
      loader: "file-loader", // or url-loader
      options: {
        ...,
        esModule: false,
      }
    }]
  ]
}
```

If you wish to use variables with `require`, you may need to change the syntax, see this [other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36387544/require-variable-with-html-webpack-plugin) and [this example on Github](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/issues/632#issuecomment-291019610):

```js
// webpack.config.js
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    image: '/path/to/image.png',
})
```

```html
<!-- index.ejs -->
<img src="<%=require('html!./' +htmlWebpackPlugin.options.image + '.html' ) %>" alt="image text">
```

Comment: how would you do this if your image source is already a variable? ie this doesn't work <%= require(slide.image) %>

Comment: see this other [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36387544/require-variable-with-html-webpack-plugin), apparently something like: `${ require('html!./' +htmlWebpackPlugin.options.environment.templateUrl + '.html' ) }`